# How to Iterate Null Separated Results in non-Bash Shell

Tags: bash, shell

Okay, so I have a script processing the null-separated output of `find`, and I can easily process this using a bash shell like so:

```
#!/bin/sh
find "$1" -print0 | while read -rd '' path; do echo "$path"; done
```

Fairly silly example since it just converts the results to new-lines anyway, but it's just to give you an idea of what I'm looking to do. This basic method works great, and avoids potential issues due to files possibly containing new-lines on various file-systems.

However, I need to do the same thing on a non-bash shell, which means I lose support for `read -d`. So, without resorting to bash (or other shell) specific features, is there a way that I can process null-separated results similarly to the above?

If not, what is the best to protect myself against new-lines in results? I was thinking I could perhaps use the `-exec` option of `find` to replace new-lines in file names with some kind of escaped value, but I'm not sure of the best way to find and replace the new-lines (I can't use `tr` for example) or what replacement to use, which is why null-characters are the best option if available.

Comment: really frustrating answers to this question. i want to parse `env -0` and modify variables, so xargs is a no go and find has nothing to do with my problem. all the answers here are find or xargs centric. I want to know how to iterate null separated results in a non-bash shell, not in some frelling subshell! answer the title, someone, please, i beg you.

Comment: @rektide The answer to the exact question in the title is that you can use `read -rd ''` in zsh, which is a non-bash shell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020).

You can e.g. use `find -exec`:

```
find [...] -exec <command> {} \;
```

or `xargs -0`:

```
find [...] -print0 | xargs -r0 <command>
```

Note that in your above example you still need to set `IFS` or you will trim off leading/trailing whitespace:

```
while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
   do_something_with "${file}"
done
```

You are right, it's a real bummer that this `read` only properly works in `bash`. I usually don't give a damn about possible newlines in filenames and just make sure that otherwise portable code doesn't break if they occur (as opposed to ignoring the problem and your script exploding) which I believe suffices for most scenarios, e.g.

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
    [ -e "${file}" ] || continue # skip over truncated filenames due to newlines
    do_something_file "${file}"
done < <(find [...])
```

or use `globbing` (when possible) which behaves correctly:

```
for file in *.foo; do
    [ -e "${file}" ] || continue # or use nullglob
    do_something_file "${file}"
done
```

Comment: @mklement0 Good catch, so is `-print0` :-) That's why I, in most cases, do what I explained that I do which works in any POSIX-compatible shell (if you replace the process substitution by a `find | while read` loop) instead of bothering about null-separation. In the first example the `[ -e ]` is necessary to avoid processing truncated filenames due to possible newlines and the `[ -e ]` in the second example is needed because `file` might expand to the literal `*.foo` if there is are no matching files (since `shopt -s nullglob` is not portable either, I prefer the explicit test).

Comment: I guess it comes down to what your requirements are, (non-)`bash` but `GNU`-userland vs. any of `bash`/`ksh`(/`zsh`) with `POSIX`-userland vs. a "plain" `POSIX` shell with a `POSIX`-userland. I personally don't like targetting the first scenario/environment.

Comment: Thanks for all that; didn't know that `-print0` is non-POSIX. Came so close, though :) "Other implementations have added other ways to get around this problem, notably a -print0 primary that wrote filenames with a null byte terminator. This was considered here, but not adopted." - http://man.cx/find  That said, `-print0` may be more widely implemented than `xargs -r`, judging by a sample of 1 other platform family :) - those with BSD heritage, which includes OSX.

Comment: I would have fully agreed but I gave it a quick google and it seems that all of NetBSD, OpenBSD and FreeBSD ship with an `xargs` that supports `-r` these days to be `GNU`-compatible, it's just Apple's old BSD implementation that doesn't ship with `-r` so I partly agree :) Just another reason why I avoid this mess by not trying to process filenames with newlines and just make my code failsafe so it wouldn't explode.

Comment: Excellent point, thanks for sleuthing. It's a bummer that some of the stuff in OSX is so outdated.

Comment: Agreed, [they even removed (!) `grep`'s `-P` option recently](http://www.dirtdon.com/?p=1452). That's kinda beyond words ...

Comment: Great answer, unfortunately I don't think I can support `xargs` at all on my targeted systems (Synology NASes really throw a spanner in the works for shell scripting). So I think I'll have to try your suggestion about double-checking the existence of file-names, but maybe use a look-ahead to try to "fix" file-names with new-lines instead. Also thanks for reminding me about the `IFS=`, I forgot that in my example! Actually, it just occurred me I might be able to exploit the structure of find results, since they should have a consistent start for valid lines (in my example the value of `$1`).

Comment: @Adrian: Agreed (and thanks for clearing that up). Generally, the issue with OSX appears to be about _licensing_ (things aren't updated, because Apple doesn't like the license attached to newer versions). Interestingly, current versions of FreeBSD now ship with *GNU* grep.

Comment: @Haravikk You could use `inotifywait` to fix filenames with newlines on the fly but I guess it might not be worth the overhead.

Comment: This code doesn't protect the user from maliciously chosen filenames. Someone may have created a directory called "\n" (a single newline) and put files in it, e.g. `mkdir -p $'\n'/etc; touch $'\n'/etc/passwd`. If it appears in a newline-terminated file list, there will be a line saying `/etc/passwd`, which means that your `[ -e "${file}" ] || continue` test won't help and /etc/passwd will be processed.

Comment: While I think `-print0` works in most reasonable environment, one should be able to emulate it using `find -exec 'printf "%s\x00"' \;`

Comment: or even better `find -exec printf '%s\x00' {} +`

Answer (score 8):

Adding to [Adrian Frühwirth's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22763005/45375):

Here is a **strictly POSIX-compliant solution**, both in terms of the shell code *and* the utilities and their options used:

```bash
find . -exec sh -c 'for f in "$@"; do printf "%s\n" "$f"; done' - {} +
```

This avoids both `find`'s `-print0` and `read -d`.

**Note**: There's a - largely hypothetical - risk that your shell code will be invoked *more than once*, namely when there are so many input filenames that their combined byte count is too large to be passed to a single `sh -c` call - see [this article about `ARG_MAX`](https://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/various/argmax/) for details and [blubberdiblub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/794539/blubberdiblub)'s comments below.
That is,  `-exec ... +`, like `xargs`, is mindful of the `ARG_MAX` limit and spreads argument sets that are too large across *multiple* calls.

Comment: Thanks for this addition, but I should probably have specified in my question that the reason I'm already using `-exec` is because I need to call a function, which `find` doesn't appear to be able to do (it has its own "clean" scope), but this is what I'd do if I could!

Comment: @Haravikk: Thanks for clarifying. (As an aside: _if_ you were able to use `bash` (I know you can't, unfortunately), you could export functions with `export -f`, then `find` would see them too (when combined with `-exec bash -c`.)

Comment: +1, but can you elaborate on the chance of the `-exec` being invoked more than once? [POSIX states](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html) that *"The size of any set of two or more pathnames shall be limited such that execution of the utility does not cause the system's `ARG_MAX` limit to be exceeded."* but that can also be interpreted as that it's OK to truncate/fail on hitting `ARG_MAX` and ...

Comment: ... e.g. on my Cygwin installation at work `ARG_MAX` is only `32k` which means hitting the limit is way more likely and less hypothetical (but the same applies to my globbing example which is also subject to `ARG_MAX`). I admit I don't know how different `find` implementations actually behave and interpret POSIX but the way I read it you cannot be certain that this works for all traversed paths. What's your knowledge on this?

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth: The source you quote also states "pathnames for which the primary is evaluated shall be aggregated into sets.". Together with what you quote I interpret this to mean that the _sole reason to group the arguments into sets (plural)_ is to work around the `ARG_MAX` limitation - otherwise you could simply always use a _single_ set and have it potentially break. (You only get in trouble should a _single_ pathname be so long as to result in a command line whose length exceeds `ARG_MAX`.)

Comment: To be honest I didn't read the whole paragraph and this makes total sense (and I concur), thanks :-)

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth: gerne; as for using globs - they're actually NOT subject to `ARG_MAX` per se ("[shell] expansion is only limited by the virtual memory system resources" - http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/) - `ARG_MAX` only comes into play when an _external_ utility is invoked.

Comment: FWIW, a single full filename with path is subject to `PATH_MAX` (typically 4096 for popular linux filesystems), which is usually exhausted before reaching the `ARG_MAX` limit. Unless of course there are additional huge arguments that cause the sum of command name/path, environment, args and null terminators to exceed `ARG_MAX` ;)

Comment: @mklement0 No, `find -exec foo {} +` works similar to `xargs` in that regard (however, documentation for this seems to be missing from the Linux manpage). That is it accumulates arguments into the call as long as it doesn't exceed ARG_MAX (or some lower limit) and in the face of excessively many arguments it performs **multiple** calls, like `xargs` does. Try something like `find / -exec echo {} + | wc -l` to see that there are multiple output lines, hence `echo` was called more than once with the arguments broken up into sets.

Comment: @mklement0 And also (not that it's very relevant to the point at hand, but just to raise awareness of how it actually works behind the scenes) it doesn't construct a space-separated command line. It directly constructs NUL-terminated C-style-strings for passing to the `exec*()` family of calls after `fork()`ing or alternatively `clone*()`, but **not** `system()`. I.e. it doesn't pass the call through a shell (unless you specify a shell explicitly as a command) and the `{}` for `-exec foo {} +` is a placeholder meaning "append all the items as `char *` each to the `argv[]` array".

Comment: That being said, on Windows (i.e. cygwin, MSYS, MingW or whatever) it may actually construct a space-separated command line by command-line-escaping the items before actually concatenating them, but that's still largely transparent (minus the Windows restrictions on what can be escaped/passed on a command line) to the user of `find` and doesn't matter in most practical cases.

Comment: @blubberdiblub (I've cleaned up my previous comments): To summarize (leaving Windows aside): 
`ARG_MAX` applies to the combined byte size of the `argv[]` array and the process' environment block, so even though an individual path is limited to `4096` characters, a large number of paths can exceed that (much larger) limit.  `-exec ... +`, like `xargs`, is mindful of the `ARG_MAX` limit and spreads argument sets that are too large across _multiple_ calls; I've updated the answer with a condensed version of this summary.

Answer (score 4):

The topic is "How to Iterate Null Separated Results in non-Bash Shell". So far most answers offer special solutions for `find . -print0` by actually circumventing iteration through a list of null separated strings (e.g. `find . -exec ...` or shell `globbing`).

The files "/proc/<pid>/environ" or "/proc/<pid>/cmdline" are good (Linux) examples which really require iterating through a list of null terminated strings. The only solution which will work correctly for a POSIX-only shell (e.g. dash) AFAIK is using `xargs -0` (or similar tools like `parallel -0`) as already mentioned in the answers of [Adrian Frühwirth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/612462/adrian-fr%C3%BChwirth) and [FatalError](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1172428/fatalerror):

```
#!/bin/sh
xargs -0 sh -c 'for i; do printf "%s\n" "$i"; done' my_cmd </proc/1/environ
```

The above example requires to be run as "root". It also works for strings containing newline and other special characters.

Answer (score 3):

## 1. Use `zsh`

The simplest solution is to use `zsh`, which is a non-`bash` shell that supports reading null-separated values via `read -d ""` (since version 4.2, released in 2004) and the only mainstream shell that can store nulls in variables. Moreover, the last component of the pipeline is not run in subshell in `zsh`, so variables set there are not lost. We can simply write:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
find . -print0 |while IFS="" read -r -d "" file; do
  echo "$file"
done
```

With `zsh` we can also easily avoid the problem of null separators altogether (at least in the case of `find . -print`) by using `setopt globdots`, which makes globs match hidden files, and `**`, which recurses into subdirectories. This works in basically all versions of `zsh`, even those older than 4.2:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
setopt globdots
for file in **/*; do
  echo "$file"
done
```

## 2. Use a POSIX shell and `od`

### 2.1 Use pipes

A general, POSIX-compatible solution for iterating over null separated values needs to convert the input in a way that no information is lost and nulls are converted to something else that is easier to process. We can use `od` to dump octal values of all input bytes and easily convert the data back using `printf`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

find . -print0 |od -An -vto1 |xargs printf ' %s' \
               |sed 's/ 000/@/g' |tr @ '\n' \
               |while IFS="" read -r file; do
  file=`printf '\134%s' $file`
  file=`printf "$file@"`
  file="${file%@}"
  echo "$file"
done
```

### 2.2 Use a variable to store intermediate results

Note that the `while` loop will be run in a subshell (at least in shells other than `zsh` and the original, non-public domain Korn shell), which means that variables set in that loop won't be visible in the rest of the code. If that's unacceptable, the `while` loop can be run from the main shell, and its input can be stored in a variable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

VAR=`find . -print0 |od -An -vto1 |xargs printf ' %s' \
                     |sed 's/ 000/@/g' |tr @ '\n'`
while IFS="" read -r file; do
  file=`printf '\134%s' $file`
  file=`printf "$file@"`
  file="${file%@}"
  echo "$file"
done <<EOF
$VAR
EOF
```

### 2.3 Use a temporary file to store intermediate results

If the output of the `find` command is very long, the script will be unable to store the output in the variable, and may crash. Moreover, [most shells use temporary files to implement heredocs](https://www.oilshell.org/blog/2016/10/18.html), so instead of using a variable, we might as well explicitly write to a temporary file, and avoid problems with using variables for storing intermediate results.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

TMPFILE="/tmp/$$_`awk 'BEGIN{srand(); print rand()}'`"
find . -print0 |od -An -vto1 |xargs printf ' %s' \
               |sed 's/ 000/@/g' |tr @ '\n' >"$TMPFILE"
while IFS="" read -r file; do
  file=`printf '\134%s' $file`
  file=`printf "$file@"`
  file="${file%@}"
  echo "$file"
done <"$TMPFILE"
rm -f "$TMPFILE"
```

### 2.4 Use named pipes

We may use named pipes to solve the above two problems: now reading and writing can be done in parallel, and we don't need to store intermediate results in variables. Note, however, that this might not work in Cygwin.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

TMPFILE="/tmp/$$_`awk 'BEGIN{srand(); print rand()}'`"
mknod "$TMPFILE" p
{
  exec 3>"$TMPFILE"
  find . -print0 |od -An -vto1 |xargs printf ' %s' \
                 |sed 's/ 000/@/g' |tr @ '\n' >&3
} &
while IFS="" read -r file; do
  file=`printf '\134%s' $file`
  file=`printf "$file@"`
  file="${file%@}"
  echo "$file"
done <"$TMPFILE"
rm -f "$TMPFILE"
```

## 3. Modify the above solutions to work with the original Bourne shell

The above solutions should work in any POSIX shell, but fail in the original Bourne shell, which is the default `/bin/sh` in Solaris 10 and older. This shell doesn't support the `%`-substitution, and trailing newlines in filenames need to be preserved in another way, e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

TMPFILE="/tmp/$$_`awk 'BEGIN{srand(); print rand()}'`"
mknod "$TMPFILE" p
{
  exec 3>"$TMPFILE"
  find . -print0 |od -An -vto1 |xargs printf ' %s' \
                 |sed 's/ 000/@/g' |tr @ '\n' >&3
} &
while read -r file; do
  trailing_nl=""
  for char in $file; do
    if [ X"$char" = X"012" ]; then
      trailing_nl="${trailing_nl}
"
    else
      trailing_nl=""
    fi
  done
  file=`printf '\134%s' $file`
  file=`printf "$file"`
  file="$file$trailing_nl"
  echo "$file"
done <"$TMPFILE"
rm -f "$TMPFILE"
```

## 4. Use a separator other than null

As pointed out in the comments, Haravikk's answer is not completely correct. Here is a modified version of his code that handles all sorts of strange situations, such as paths beginning with `~:/\/:` and trailing newlines in filenames. Note that it only works for relative pathnames; a similar trick can be done with absolute pathnames by prepending them with `/./`, but `read_path()` needs to be changed to handle that. This method is inspired by [Rich’s sh (POSIX shell) tricks](http://www.etalabs.net/sh_tricks.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

read_path() {
    path=
    IFS=
    read -r path || return $?
    read -r path_next || return 0
    if [ X"$path" = X"././" ]; then
        path="./"
        read -r path_next || return 0
        return
    fi
    path="./$path"
    while [ X"$path_next" != X"././" ]; do
        path=`printf '%s\n%s' "$path" "$path_next"`
        read -r path_next || return 0
    done
}

find ././ |sed 's,^\./\./,&\n,' |while read_path; do
  echo "$path"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could do is use the `xargs -0` option to pass arguments to the other shell, e.g.:

```
$ find . -print0 | xargs -0 sh -c 'for f in "$@"; do echo "$f"; done'
```

Comment: That works, but you could simplify it to `find . -exec sh -c 'for f in "$@"; do echo "$f"; done' {} +`

Comment: Beware that doing it this way will lose at least one item (one item per shell call). You forgot to specify the `command_name` argument after the shell script (i.e. `argv[0]`). Can be some insignificant string. `sh` will do fine. The reason you didn't notice is likely that your find call will also list directories, starting with `.`, so if you didn't expect directory names to show up as arguments, you may also want a `-type f` or `\! -type d` for your find call.

Answer (score 0):

Adrian Frühwirth's answer is definitely the most correct and complete, but for those interested in this issue I just wanted to share the code that I've ended up using for now:

```
NL=$'\n'
read_path() {
    path=
    IFS=
    while [ -z "$path" ]; do
        read -r path || return $?
        while [ ! -e "$path" ]; do
            read -r path_next || { path=; return $?; }
            [ "${path_next:0:6}" != '~:/\/:' -o ! -e "$find_path_next" ] && path="$path$NL$path_next" || path="$path_next"
        done
    done
}
```

This works when you run `find` like so:

```
find . -exec printf '~:/\/:%s\n' {} \; | while read_path; do echo "$path"; done
```

Since the string being added at the start of results should never appear in actual file-names (if there's a simpler string, let me know!) then it should be safe to use it when deciding whether to join results together into a single string.

I'm going to use this in combination with a test for `-print0` and `read -d` support, so I can use that for simplicity where possible, but the above should be safe, or at least it works in all of the environments I've tested thus far and seems to do the job when I can't use a prettier method; e.g - if I can't use globbing because I need more specific results from `find` or `ls`

Comment: The string you choose can appear in pathnames. Try this: `mkdir -p \~:/\\/:./ && touch \~:/\\/:./abcd && find \~: -type f`. However, there is another string that really cannot appear in pathnames: `././`.

Comment: Another problem: `touch abcd $'abcd\n'`. Since `abcd` exists, the code won't read next line, and won't be able to the file with a trailing newline.